# SQL multiple SUM with conditions in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel-5, sum

Working on a Laravel application, I need to retrieve data from a second database, which is why I have a special "DB" like this :
        `DB::connection('sqlsrv2')`.
On this database, there's a table customerAccount and a table Opportunity.
        We want to know how many opportunity we create, win or lose, each month, and for a precise year and a precise customerFamily.
I can retrieve the datas with some foreach and a query for each case (opportunity that's new, won or lost) but it ends up being a >12700 queries to do it for every customer and every month.

So I thought about SQL SUM, and that I could do it in a single (looong) query that would create 3 columns (new, won, lost). Then I would repeat the query for every month of the year selected.
The thing is, I don't remember how to do it, and I can't find any help since I don't really know what to search for.

Here's my bad attempt to write my query : [EDITED TO FOLLOW ADVICES IN COMMENTS]

```
$clients = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('customerAccount')
        ->select(DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->raw(
            "customerAccount.Name, 
  SUM(case when opportunity.customerAccountId = customerAccount.Id
  and YEAR(opportunity.OpportunityDate) = $year
  and MONTH(opportunity.OpportunityDate) = $month
  then 1
  else 0
  end) as nbOppNew,
  SUM(case when opportunity.customerAccountId = customerAccount.Id
  and YEAR(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $year
  and MONTH(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $month
  and StageProbability = 99
  then 1
  else 0
  end) as nbOppWon,
  SUM(case when opportunity.customerAccountId = customerAccount.Id
  and YEAR(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $year
  and MONTH(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $month
  and StageProbability <= 1
  then 1
  else 0
  end) as nbOppLost
  FROM
  customerAccount
  INNER JOIN opportunity ON customerAccount.Id = opportunity.customerAccountId
  WHERE
  MainInvoicingAddress_CountryIsoCode = 'ES'
  and familyId = '$family'
  GROUP BY customerAccount.Name"
        ))
        ->get();
```

The error that's generated by Laravel : `SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'from'.`

What I really want to get is a single array with the client's name, and for each : a second entry named "nbOppNew", with the SUM value in it. And a third for "nbOppWon", then the fourth with "nbOppLost".

Comment: how do you expect to do the sum with date(then opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) value?

Comment: I don't, I want to SUM up the number of time the case occurs. Should I replace `then opportunity.OpportunityDate` with `then 1` ?

Comment: Yes. You should replace the date with value 1

Comment: I'm not sure if `raw` method supports PHP variables as part of the SQL statement. Change $year to `'$year'` (`$month` and `$family` too) or use parameterized query using placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the trick. Laravel Query Builder automatically adds the 'from' statement right after your raw query. So I add a double 'from', and my join and where conditions where written BEFORE it. I used the builder's method instead and transformed my query in :

```
$clients = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('customerAccount')
        ->select(DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->raw(
            "customerAccount.Name, 
  SUM(case when opportunity.customerAccountId = customerAccount.Id
  and YEAR(opportunity.OpportunityDate) = $year
  and MONTH(opportunity.OpportunityDate) = $month
  then 1
  else 0
  end) as nbOppNew,
  SUM(case when opportunity.customerAccountId = customerAccount.Id
  and YEAR(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $year
  and MONTH(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $month
  and StageProbability = 99
  then 1
  else 0
  end) as nbOppWon,
  SUM(case when opportunity.customerAccountId = customerAccount.Id
  and YEAR(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $year
  and MONTH(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $month
  and StageProbability <= 1
  then 1
  else 0
  end) as nbOppLost"
        ))
            ->join('opportunity', 'customerAccount.Id', '=', 'opportunity.customerAccountId')
            ->where('MainInvoicingAddress_CountryIsoCode', 'ES')
            ->where('familyId', $family)
            ->groupBy('customerAccount.Name')
        ->get();
```

And it works ! Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Your error might be due to the single quotes in the select statement of first column. Remove the quotes and the error won't occur.

```
       "SELECT customerAccount.Name,
  SUM(case when opportunity.customerAccountId = customerAccount.Id
  and YEAR(opportunity.OpportunityDate) = $year
  and MONTH(opportunity.OpportunityDate) = $month
  then opportunity.OpportunityDate
```

Also use the non-aggregate columns(**Name**) in the select in group by. You are grouping based on **id**. If grouping based on id is needed then use id in the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

remove th single quote for customerAccount.Name and use sigle quote for ES  value

```
     "SELECT customerAccount.Name,
      SUM(case when opportunity.customerAccountId = customerAccount.Id
      and YEAR(opportunity.OpportunityDate) = $year
      and MONTH(opportunity.OpportunityDate) = $month
      then opportunity.OpportunityDate
      else 0
      end) as nbOppNew,
      SUM(case when opportunity.customerAccountId = customerAccount.Id
      and YEAR(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $year
      and MONTH(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $month
      and StageProbability = 99
      then opportunity.OpportunityDate
      else 0
      end) as nbOppWon,
      SUM(case when opportunity.customerAccountId = customerAccount.Id
      and YEAR(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $year
      and MONTH(opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate) = $month
      and StageProbability <= 1
      then opportunity.OpportunityCloseDate
      else 0
      end) as nbOppLost
      FROM
      customerAccount
      INNER JOIN opportunity ON customerAccount.Id = opportunity.customerAccountId
      WHERE
      MainInvoicingAddress_CountryIsoCode = 'ES'
      and familyId = $family
      GROUP BY customerAccount.Name"
```

and as suggestion  use group by customerAccount.Name

Comment: Thanks, and since you mentionned it, I saw that $family wasn't passed so I added single quotes around it too : '$family'

Comment: each string var must be enclosed  in single quote  ..  (obviously  i can't image if a var you are using is a string or a number .. )  but if the value in db is a number don't use single quote..

Answer (score 1):

In the way you have written the query there is no actual syntax error. So I'd expect this has something to do with the escape of the single quotes in your query. But the query itself executes just fine.

However, there are few problems:

- the `SUM` on date values is suspicious and should most probably be reworked, as you are not allowed to sum dates
- the `GROUP BY` is by `ID`, whereas you try to select `Name`

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question with those advices, sadly I still have an error.